# Duvidas de relacionamento no MySql WorkBench

Tags: mysql

Sou novo no fórum e conto com a ajuda de vocês em uma questão que ocorre no MySql Workbench.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz uma pequena modelagem para explicar minha dúvida.
Gostaria de entender por que ao relacionar uma tabela que já possui uma chave estrangeira, o WorkBench gera nessa tabela que está sendo relacionada as chaves estrangeiras da tabela anterior.
Igual no modelo acima, a tabela Endereço puxou o relacionamento de `Pessoa/Funcionário`.
Poderiam me ajudar nessa questão?

OBS: Essa modelagem foi apenas para mostrar a dúvida em questão.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você está definindo a coluna `Pessoa_idPessoa` da tabela `Funcionario`, como `Primary key`, basta removê-lo e refazer a relação para solucionar o seu problema.
[image: Solução para o Problema]

Comment: Vlw Vitor.
Não tinha reparado isso, porem o próprio workbench esta jogando como primary key, seria algum bug ou configuração?

Comment: Normalmente o Workbench define automaticamente como Primary Key apenas os id's, não sei te dizer o que pode estar ocorrendo com a chave estrangeira em si...
Espero ter ajudado, caso tenha mais alguma dúvida (se eu souber responder)...

Comment: Possui alguma versão que contenha nas configs da tabela a opção foreingn keys?

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta.
Chave estrangeira (foreign key) é o campo que estabelece o relacionamento entre duas tabelas.

Comment: Sim, foi mal, queria falar alguma opção que define como chave estrangeira.
Tipo, cada vez que for relacionar, terei que desabilitar a chave primaria?

Comment: Mano, descobri oque faz essa questão da chave estrangeira ir para a proxima tabela relacionada.
Vacilo meu nas chaves sobre os ligamento identificados com os não identificados.
Agora vai dar certo aqui, Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Denada, precisando estamos aí... ^^

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde o relacionamento está incorreto.

Pergunte-se se funcionário é uma pessoa ou funcionário tem uma pessoa.

Assim acaba ficando simples de se resolver o seu problema.

Funcionário é uma pessoa então estamos agregando uma classe filha à classe pai Pessoa. Os Ids tem que ter o mesmo valor. Não é necessário você add uma pessoa dentro da classe que herda de pessoa no caso funcionário.